# Zero-Sum Partitions of Nonzero Elements of a Ring

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, number-theory, ring-theory, finite-rings

In this question, rings are not necessarily finite nor do they need to be unital (i.e., the multiplicative identity may not exist).  Although I shall almost exclusively discuss finite commutative unital rings, I shall not assume finiteness, commutativity, or unitality in the definitions.  For a ring $R$, $0_R$ denotes the additive identity and we shall write $\text{Units}(R )$ for the set of all units in $R$.

> **Definition 1:**  A ring $R$ is said to be *bekifft* iff, for any collection $\left\{r_j\right\}_{j\in J}$ of integers $r_j >1$ such that $\sum_{j \in J}\,r_j=\big|R\setminus\left\{0_R\right\}\big|$, there exists a partition $\left\{S_j\right\}_{j\in J}$ of $R\setminus\left\{0_R\right\}$ such that $\left|S_j\right|=r_j$ and $\sum_{x\in S_j}\,x=0_R$ for every $j\in J$.
>
> **Definition 2:**  A ring $R$ is said to be *betrunken* iff, for any collection $\left\{r_j\right\}_{j\in J}$ of integers $r_j >1$ such that $\sum_{j \in J}\,r_j=\big|\text{Units}(R )\big|$, there exists a partition $\left\{S_j\right\}_{j\in J}$ of $\text{Units}(R)$ such that $\left|S_j\right|=r_j$ and $\sum_{x\in S_j}\,x=0_R$ for every $j\in J$.

**Remark:**  In the case where $J$ is an infinite index set, $\sum_{j\in J}\,r_j$ is simply $|J|$.

**Examples:**  The zero ring is vacuously bekifft and betrunken.  The ring $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ is both bekifft and betrunken.  (Note that *bekifft-ness* and *betrunken-ness* are the same concept for fields.) The ring $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is not bekifft, while it is betrunken.  The ring $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$ is bekifft, but not betrunken.  The ring $\mathbb{Z}/14\mathbb{Z}$ is neither bekifft nor betrunken.

Clearly, if a finite ring $R$ with at least three elements is bekifft, then $\sum_{x\in R}\,x=0_R$; if a ring $R$ with $\big|\text{Units}(R )\big|\geq 2$ is betrunken, then $\sum_{x\in \text{Units}(R )}\,x=0_R$.  Below are three relatively easy propositions.  While I am not giving a proof here, I guarantee that these propositions are not difficult.

> **Proposition 1:** For a ring $R$, define $$\text{Ann}_R(2):=\left\{x\in R\,\big|\,2x=0_R\right\}\,.$$ 
>   If a finite ring $R$ with at least three elements is such that $\text{Ann}_R(2)$ has a nonzero sum, then $R$ is not bekifft.
>
> **Proposition 2:**  For every even positive integer $n>2$, $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is not bekifft.  If $\phi(n)\geq 6$ as well, then $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is not betrunken.  (Here, $\phi$ is Euler's totient function.)
>
> **Proposition 3:**  For an odd positive prime $p$, let $q:=p^k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $q\equiv 1\pmod{3}$.  Then, the field $\mathbb{F}_q$ is both bekifft and betrunken.

**Remark:** Proposition 2 implies that, of all even positive integers greater than $2$, only $n\in\{4,6,8,10,12\}$ are possible values such that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ may be betrunken.  It turns out that all of such rings indeed are betrunken.

Here come the main questions.  Note that the answer to Question 2 is partially known (see Proposition 3).

> **Question 1:** Let $n$ be an odd positive integer.  When is the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ bekifft?  When is it betrunken?
>
> **Question 2:** Let $F$ be a finite field.  When is $F$ bekifft (equivalently, betrunken)?
>
> **Question 3:** Is there an infinite ring which is bekifft?  Is there a ring with infinitely many units which is betrunken?

Comment: Please chose some less colorful terminology.

Comment: Why the seriousness?  :D

Comment: There are at least three aspect: 1) introducing words from another language makes the thing hard to read, especially for those that do not know that other language. (Sure it sometimes is done, but to do it gratuitously seems pointless) It also leads to weird constructs like bekifft-ness.  2) The words to me make no sense there. If the words would at least relate well to the property. But why would the one ring be called "stoned" and the other "drunk" it is quite unclear to me.

Comment: 3) While the words used are not really problematic, the one being a completely common word and the other only slightly slang, they are still such that they set a tone that might not be optimal for the site. I do not see what is gained when posts are sprinkled with quasi-randomly chosen  "funny" words.  Anyway: please change this.

Comment: I won't.  There is no point in choosing such words, but that is the point.  Your not liking the words I use doesn't make the question meaningless.  If you don't like the way the question is phrased, you don't have to read or try to understand it.  If you can't take a little bit of jokes here and there, then it is not my problem.

Comment: Reminds me of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/88957/zero-sum-partition-of-an-abelian-group .

Comment: Also, I believe that the equivalent of "betrunken" belonging to the same register as "bekifft" would be "besoffen".

Comment: A proof for Proposition 2 is somewhat similar to what you wrote in that link.  I can change betrunken to besoffen if you want, but I like the sound of betrunken more.

Comment: I meant Proposition 3.